# How do I launch a PHP file using command line

Tags: php, windows, command-line

Specifically I'm looking at Symphony and I'm running through [this](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/02-Prerequisites) page. It suggests that I launch a file using command line.

**OS:** Windows Visa 32

Any help?

Comment: Need a bit more information, what OS are you trying to launch it on? In linux it should just be `php -f filename.php`  in Windows, if php is not in the `PATH` you have to browse to the directory where php.exe is and run that same command with the path to the `filename.php`.

Comment: That page describes exactly how to do it - what have you tried so far? What operating system are you on? More information could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command line, and type

```
php check_configuration.php
```

(Press Enter after that).

If you're trying to execute php on Windows, you need to [set up your PATH variable](https://superuser.com/questions/25037/change-environment-variables-as-standard-user-windows-7) to include the php binary directory beforehand.

If you're on a POSIX-compatible system (Linux/Mac OS X) and you're getting a "command not found error message", you need to install php and its CLI interface, often in a package `php-cli` or similar.

Comment: Need to check php.exe is in PATH first. Depending on platform this may vary. In Linux it should be in PATH by default (assuming php_cli is installed) but on Windows it probably won't be.

Comment: @joshb Updated with a descriptoin.

Comment: might want to mention installing the php_cli package on Linux? (Know you have to on Ubuntu although not sure about other distros)

Comment: @joshb He updated the question to include OS: win6, but I added your comment to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be able to do `php -f somefile.php`.  See the [PHP command line manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) for more info.  The link you gave also shows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly what it says on that page:

`php server_check.php`

Assuming you are in the dir containing servercheck.php.

Most of the other symfony commands actually use a single file you can invoke those with

`symfony namespace:task [options] [arguments]`

or

`php symfony namespace:task [options] [arguments]`

Comment: Thanks, what threw me was the '$'. I'm not familiar with command-line, so I put this in too. Why is that there?

Comment: @Gary Ryan The `$` just means "Enter this in the command line". It's the last character of the shell prompt in most UNIX shells. On Windows, with `cmd.exe`, `>` is used instead; the full prompt looks like `C:\>`.

Answer (score 0):

When it says to run that file, basically its the same as pasting that file to the directory of symphony's php config files, and then running it in your browser.